# Binding to internal ViewModel-Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, internal

I have a UserControl with a ViewModel class as DataContext:

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="DotfuscatorTest.UserControl.View.UserControlView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" >    
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewModelProperty}"/>
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

CodeBehind:

```
namespace DotfuscatorTest.UserControl.View
{
   using ViewModel;
   public partial class UserControlView
   {
      public UserControlView()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         DataContext = new UserControlViewModel();         
      }
   }
}
```

ViewModel class:

```
namespace DotfuscatorTest.UserControl.ViewModel
{
   public class UserControlViewModel
   {
      private string viewModelProperty = "hello world";

      internal string ViewModelProperty
      {
        get { return viewModelProperty; }
        set { viewModelProperty = value; }
      }
   }
}
```

If I set the ViewModelProperty to public the binding works fine. But if I set the property to internal like above the binding fails (Binding error: property not found... ).

I thought an internal property is accessible like public in same assembly. Also I can access to the property from UserControl-codebehind without any problem:

```
{
...

((UserControlViewModel)DataContext).ViewModelProperty = "hallo viewmodel";

...
```

Any explenation for this behavior?

Thanks in advance,
rhe1980

Comment: You should have taken a look on DataBinding docs before.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx)

> The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must
>   be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface
>   properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected,
>   private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base
>   implementation.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I thought in point of view of the property is the same if the class is public and the property is internal like when the class is internal and the property public. But seems link not :-)...